# How "synthetic division" is called in Germany?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, mathematics

How is [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) called in Germany?

Comment: You might mention, that there is no german Wikipedia article linked to the english one, for easily finding an answer.

Answer (score 9):

I think it would be referred to either generally as **Polynomdivision** / **Partialdivision**, which is the general term for polynomial division, or alternatively as **das Horner-Schema**. We have that name in English too; Horner's Scheme/Rule/Method, and in both languages as far as I understand it's not exactly the same as saying "synthetic division" in English, but it's the underlying principle behind synthetic division. To my knowledge (and after doing some research), there isn't a more specific term for synthetic division in German.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner-Schema

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method

From the English Wikipedia page on Horner's Method:

> "...synthetic division is based on Horner's method."

Source: https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=887602&idForum=1&lang=de&lp=ende

Comment: I can testify that students in german Switzerland never heard about "synthetische Division" but many heard about Horner Schema.

Comment: "Polynomdivision" is definitely the standard expression.  A Google search gives 1.800.000 hits, "synthetische Division" only 65.000.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy: "synthetische Division"

Comment: There is no this method in German wiki. Is it popular in Germany? Maybe it has another name?

Comment: @AndrewFount _"Is it popular in Germany?"_ Well, that's more a question for the mathematicians rather than the language specialists. I think that translation should be correct.

Comment: I have never heard of it, but I get hits with Google.

Answer (score 1):

Looks indeed to be easy: **Synthetische Division**

https://de.wikihow.com/Synthetische-Division-verwenden-um-Polynome-zu-dividieren